# Build Angular 2 with CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

1. I build project with **angular cli**. The project is run, but the error appears in the console.

   [image]

I clicked VM223 and see

[image]

I think I forgot to connect some library or something like that. How can I solve this problem? Can someone experienced this?

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.30",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.34",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "^1.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
```

**angular-cli**

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/ng2-facebook-sdk/dist/ng2-facebook-sdk.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ]
```

**polyfills.ts**

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es6/promise';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/client/shim.min';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <main>
            <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. When I use **ng build -prod**, I get folder dist with styles, images, fonts, and other resources required for your application. But I thought that there must be index.html and bundles file without images, fonts etc.

After building I have:

[image]

Maybe I do something wrong?

Regards

Comment: are you using external templates in component

Comment: @Rahul Singh Yes, I am using, if I understand you correctly

Comment: and you are using something like template:require('./your.component.html')
if you are please try and use templateUrl:'./your.component.html'

Comment: this is my decorator
`@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styles: [` 
        .active a {
         color:#fff;
        }
    `]
})`

Comment: can you please try unistalling angular cli and then reinstalling it

Comment: I reinstalling all node_modules, but nothing happened

Comment: Are you using cli to create angualr project or using any seed

Comment: I did a project and then I used cli. So I create a new angular-cli project and carefully copied all existing files.

Comment: Please try and create tje project using tje following command after installing cli . Use ng new project_name .

Comment: I did the same steps.
1. install global cli
2. ng new project_name
3. copied all existing files
4. project started but with error in console

Comment: Without copying files when u do ng serve does it run fine, if so there is some problem with the filea you are copying

Comment: When I create a new project with cli and run it - all works perfectly

Comment: Then its the issue with the code you are pasting it might have some dependencies you need to resolve by installing , you have not listed that code here too

Comment: exactly, the first time I use angular-cli and I suppouse I have problem with **angular-cli.json** or **polyfills.ts**, where we configure dependencies.
I think I provided all necessary files. I really confused with all of this.

Comment: `require is not defined` sounds like an issue with a dynamic import. Do you have a webpack.config file?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you need to install the package "require".

```
npm install require --save
```

should do the trick.

EDIT: The build --prod is a normal output, it serves you all the static files needed and bundles the css & javascript.

EDIT2: You get that error in your browser ? "Require" is a Node.JS package, it's Server Sided Scripting, which means it can be used in your browser.

Take a look at this: http://requirejs.org/ For client side.

EDIT3:

```
var express = require('express')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()

app.use(serveStatic('.', {'index': ['index.html']}))
app.listen(3000)
```

Make a Server.js file,put the code above in it, put it in your dist after you build it, and run the following command

```
node Server.js
```

it's possible that you need to install express and serve-static, for purpose to check if this works, install them gobally, you can always remove them later and install them locally later:

```
npm install -g express
npm install -g serve-static
```

Comment: This does not change anything at my place...same error

Comment: I have tried to install requirejs and connect it to angular-cli.json, but nothing happened. I'm still the same error. I really don't understand what's happening

Comment: You're trying to run something which is meant to be ran on a server, not a client. The thing is when angular-cli bundles the package, you should try to serve the static files ( the files in 'dist') with a Node.JS server. Check my edit 3

Comment: I have tried your advice, but I have still the same error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

First you delete the node modules:

and make your pacage.json like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.3.1",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.30",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.34",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.33.3",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "1.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.35",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.42",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.40",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  }
```

and then run command npm install again, hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happened.